# How to run a specific set of code when Python is launched

Tags: python, printing

I apologize if I sound naive, as I am still a beginner in Python. However, I was wondering if there is a way for Python to automatically run a code whenever the application is launched.

For context, I'd like Python to print 'Welcome, Robert' in block letters like in [this movie clip](https://youtu.be/X5ge0pd7hMQ?t=162), but I'm not sure how to do that. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you wants to print it as soon as you start Python in interactive mode or do you just want to print it as part of a script ?

Comment: No, I'd like it to print as soon as I first start Python.

Comment: In that case the answer given below won't work I guess. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

> you have to store that `welcome message` in raw python string & print it.

- For generating such message you can use any script or online tools.

like `figlet` for example:

[image]

```
welcome_msg = r"""
 ____  _      _            
|  _ \(_) ___| |_ ___ _ __ 
| | | | |/ _ \ __/ _ \ '__|
| |_| | |  __/ ||  __/ |   
|____/|_|\___|\__\___|_|  
"""

print(welcome_msg)
```

---

`**Python**`

[image]